# zsh: command not found: npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I have just installed Node and Yarn using the following commands:

```
brew install node
brew install yarn --without-node

node -v       
v11.8.0

-a node  
node is /usr/local/bin/node

yarn -v       
1.13.0
type -a yarn
yarn is /usr/local/bin/yarn
```

However, if I write in terminal `npm` is says "zsh: command not found: npm"

In my: `~/.zshrc` I have:

```
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# You can change the theme with another one:
#   https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Useful plugins for Rails development with Sublime Text
plugins=(gitfast last-working-dir common-aliases sublime zsh-syntax-highlighting history-substring-search)

# Prevent Homebrew from reporting - https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Analytics.md
export HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS=1

# Actually load Oh-My-Zsh
source "${ZSH}/oh-my-zsh.sh"
unalias rm # No interactive rm by default (brought by plugins/common-aliases)

# Load rbenv if installed
export PATH="${HOME}/.rbenv/bin:${PATH}"
type -a rbenv > /dev/null && eval "$(rbenv init -)"

# Rails and Ruby uses the local `bin` folder to store binstubs.
# So instead of running `bin/rails` like the doc says, just run `rails`
# Same for `./node_modules/.bin` and nodejs
export PATH="./bin:./node_modules/.bin:${PATH}:/usr/local/sbin"

# Store your own aliases in the ~/.aliases file and load the here.
[[ -f "$HOME/.aliases" ]] && source "$HOME/.aliases"

# Encoding stuff for the terminal
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Node and Yarn using this guide: [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

But I still get the same error.

Comment: which what user you installed `node` or `yarn`? and are you running it with same user or different user?

Comment: Same user. I managed to solve is by uninstall node completely and download it from the website (not installing it via terminal). Now, however, I get an error message when I run "yarn start".

Comment: Check - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75472094/5348972

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it by uninstalling Node completely and installing it via the website (not via terminal)

Answer (score 8):

It worked for me when I added `source ~/.bash_profile` at the beginning of my `~/.zshrc` and I had to also remove

```
test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash"
```

in `~/.bash_profile`. This was the shell integration I accidentally installed from iTerm2.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by running `brew uninstall node` and downloading the latest node installing .pkg from [their website](https://nodejs.org/it/).

Answer (score 1):

solved by selecting a node version using nvm.

```
nvm ls
```

then

```
nvm use _version_code
```